# Binding events onClick on bootstrap buttons in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick, bootstrapping

ok i'm new to bootstrap themes and all. I have downloaded a bootstrap template for the internet and trying to edit it for my personal project. I'm running it on asp.net framework. I want to add some action when a bootstrap button is clicked in the cs file but can't find the way. In the aspx file the button is declared as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Log In</button>
                        </div>
```

now I want to write some code about what should happen when this button is clicked but can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Since your button is inside a form tag, you page will be submitted. In Page_Load you can check out the paramenters from you form and do any action you want

Comment: can you explain in a bit detail

Comment: I think you probably have your submit button inside a form tag, like this:  <form action="YourPage.aspx"> ...... <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Log In</button> ....... </form>. When you click the button, the page will be posted and the Form_Load method of your aspx.cs file will be hit. There you can handle any actions you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Log in" />
```

You are pointing the class, so it seams to be the same

Comment: It doesn't work. I wrote the function in the cs file for btnLogin_Click. no output

Comment: do u use TeamViewer? If yes, I would like to connect to your computer and help you

Comment: i am afraid i don't but i can download it now and let you know when it's done. It will be really helpful